# How can I quickly make a text file unreadable to humans?

Tags: php, string, encoding, obfuscation

I want to encode a text file in the fastest way possible, just make it unreadable by humans.

Maybe flipping the first bit of each byte, or something that can be done very quickly so that it doesn't slow down the script. The text file will be several MB in length, so whatever is the fastest method possible to make it unreadable.

Comment: What, you want `rot13()`, or something?  That is close to what you're asking for, but who knows if it is efficient.  You'd have to benchmark the various functions yourself to see.

Comment: This isn't encrypting, it's encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file consists mostly of numbers, you could try XORing it with, say, `'0'`.  That will map all numbers to unprintable control codes, which should make the file hard to read without a hex editor.

```
$n = strlen($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) $str[$i] = $str[$i] ^ '0';
```

In practice, it will most likely be faster to avoid the loop using either `str_repeat()`:

```
$str ^= str_repeat('0', strlen($str));
```

or `strtr()`:

```
$from = $to = "x";
for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) {
    $from[$i] = chr($i);
    $to[$i] = chr($i) ^ '0';
}
$str = strtr($str, $from, $to);
```

Of the solutions above, the last one seems to be fastest for long strings, with a throughput of about 10 Mb/s on my computer.  The `str_repeat()` solution works well for fairly short strings, but suffers from excessive memory usage with longer strings.

Of course, none of these solutions provide any security against someone with a hex editor and two brain cells to rub together.  For that, you'd need real encryption.

Answer (score 5):

Throw the contents through a single pass of ROT13.

```
file_put_contents($filename, str_rot13(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Or, through `base64_encode`:

```
file_put_contents($filename, base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
```

A quick test tells me there is no significant difference in speed.

Comment: Unbelievable :) I thought I would be the only one to brave the potential downvotes by suggesting rot13.  +1 for getting there first.

Comment: That is what I asked for, but since there is a dedicated function in PHP specifically that does this, I think it would be rather obvious to anyone who wanted to decode it. Also, there is the fact that my text file consists of number, not letters.

Comment: Then use `base64_encode` instead of `str_rot13`. It will handle any character.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something that encrypts at the binary level already. Here it is, adapted for you:

```
// Hexadecimal to String
//  Usage: hextostr(STRING_HEXADECIMAL);
function hextostr($x)
  { 
  $s = '';
  foreach (explode("\n", trim(chunk_split($x, 2))) as $h)
    $s .= chr(hexdec($h));
  return $s;
  } 

// String to Hexadecimal
//  Usage: strtohex(STRING);
function strtohex($x)
  { 
  $s = '';
  foreach (str_split($x) as $c)
    $s .= sprintf("%02X", ord($c));
  return $s;
  }

  function encrypt($log_raw)
    {
    // Convert binary log file to hexadecimal
    $log_hex = $this->strtohex($log_raw);

    // Split hexadecimal values into an array of bytes
    $log_hex_array = str_split($log_hex, 2);

    // Flip the binary data around
    foreach ($log_hex_array as $key => $log_hex_byte)
      {
      $log_hex_array[$key] = strrev($log_hex_byte);
      }

    // Return the encoded data
    return implode("", $log_hex_array);
    }
```

Now, all you need to do is pass your string through `encrypt`, and it will be encoded at the binary level. Pass the string into `encrypt` again to decode the string.

I haven't actually tested the performance of that, but knowing PHP, it might be slower than you desire.  Still, try it out, nevertheless.

Comment: @Alasdair You shouldn't use this since your primary concern is speed. There are better encryption algorithms built into PHP, which will be orders of magnitude faster because they're implemented in C.